# Slow Ubuntu 20.04 installation: warning: source ID xxxx was not found when attempting to remove it

Tags: acer, usb-installation, ubiquity

My Acer Aspire became very slow with Windows 10 running on it so I formatted my hard disc on my acer Aspire laptop and tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 but the installation takes hours and constantly hangs at **/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nwidgets.py:xx: warning: source ID xxxx was not found when attempting to remove it  Glib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id** (xxxx the number goes up)

I made various attempts trying to find a solution but it is still the same. I could finish the installation last night but then it froze at black screen with Ubuntu and the spinning wheel that froze and that was it (I later thought I could have tried nomodeset)

But now I am stuck at another slow installation attempt.
Could this be the hard drive that is not good? I saw that when I tried Ubuntu: Disk likely to fail soon.
Or could there be a solution? So I can install Ubuntu on my laptop.

This does not look good.
[image]

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. Start the `Disks` app. Take screenshot(s) of the SMART Data window and edit them into your question, and I'll take a look.

Comment: Your disk is failing. This is a hardware issue.

Comment: Thank you @heynnema, I am affraid this does not look good, I added the screenshot.

Comment: This looks really bad. Consider replacing the disk.

Comment: Yes @Pilot6 I realised that. Going to get a new disk.

Comment: Backup your important files asap!

Comment: Yes, thank you, I did that last night. @heynnema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

After reviewing the disk SMART Data values, it looks like your HDD is failing.

Backup your important files asap.

Order a replacement HDD or SSD.

Don't try and clone/backup your current disk to the new disk, as you'll probably only get a corrupt copy. Reinstall Ubuntu from fresh, and then restore your backed up data files.