# Ubuntu Studio 20.04 installation freezes at restart window at the end

Tags: boot, sound, laptop, hdmi, usb-installation

After having some trouble in Windows 10 that was actually a failing hard drive see this: [Slow Ubuntu 20.04 installation: warning: source ID xxxx was not found when attempting to remove it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240997/slow-ubuntu-20-04-installation-warning-source-id-xxxx-was-not-found-when-attem) I bought a new 1TB hard drive and put it in my Acer Aspire 5560G today and I tried to install Ubuntu Studio 20.04.

I have now been through 4 installations, but I can not finish the installation, it mostly freezes with the restart window at the end, so I have not been able to make a restart.

Ater a hard shutdown I managed to get into an installation but only with recovery mode at first and later with nomodeset temporary and later permanent.
The problem after that is that I can not restart it without freezing, but shutdown and start works.
So that is one thing that does not look or feel right.
Another thing is the HDMI audio that does not work in this installation I can see video like Sky News live but no sound, sound from the laptop speaker though but not from my TV speaker.

So these are two problems I am encountering while being happy with my new 1TB hard drive,
I mainly use this laptop for watching "TV" So it's a bit of a disppointment that the installation is not working.

initramfs failed, decoding failed is what I just saw after the first start after an installation that froze. 
I am not an Ubuntu or computer expert but I use Ubuntu for a couple of years now.
I had Windows 10 on this laptop but on another hard drive and now it is supposed to be only Ubuntu.

I hope there is some advice.

Extra information:
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version: 
V1.08

free -h:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.3Gi       489Mi       6.3Gi       5.0Mi       440Mi       6.5Gi
Swap:          19Gi          0B        19Gi
```

grep -i swap /etc/fstab:

```
swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=193b09d2-689b-4b39-8746-61f44c93b56f none            swap    sw  
            0       0
```

[image]

Ah, yes, how sad (and hot)

```
sensors
BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:           6.41 V  
curr1:         0.00 A  

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +76.1°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +100.0°C, hyst = +99.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +76.0°C  (crit = +98.0°C)
temp2:        +55.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108388/discussion-on-question-by-rosarium-lane-ubuntu-studio-20-04-installation-freezes).

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema I will update when I have a new battery and fixed the overheating, that will take a couple of weeks.

Comment: Ah yes, I recall. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: @heynnema This is going to take more time. I also had a problem with my pc, so I had no computer for a while. Then I received an old Packard Bell laptop from my niece, which worked fine with Win10 on it but then that hard drive also crashed. Funny thing is that I connected the HD of my old pc to this laptop with a Sata-USB cable and I could boot into the Ubuntu that was on the HD of my old pc, without any problem and I am still using this laptop this way, with Ubuntu on an external drive that was originally installed on my pc.

Comment: @heynnema I am also receiving a refurbished pc for my birthday so I am fine right now. I might come back to the original problem of this topic with the old laptop.

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

**initramfs**

For the initramfs decoding issue, rebuild your ramdisk with...

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)
```

**BIOS**

**Note**: Have good backups before updating your BIOS.

You have BIOS 1.08.

The current BIOS is 1.15, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/ID/content/support-product/3767;-;).

Since you don't have Windows installed any more, use freeDOS, and the DOS updater that's included in the download archive.

**Swap**

Your swap is set to 19G, and that's way too much. 4G should be enough (unless you're hibernating) with 8G RAM. You either need to reduce your swap partition, or reduce your /swapfile, depending on which method that you're using.

**Overheating**

Your computer is running too hot. You'll have to disassemble the laptop, blow out any dust, especially from the fan areas. You'll also need to clean up and reapply thermal paste to the CPU (& graphics chip), where it meets its heat pipe or fan.